# Blazor Application Managing Authorization in a muli-tiered solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a solution made up of a Blazor application (Server Side app with .Net 5.0)  and a second project that is a Class Library (.Net Standard 2.0).  The Blazor app handles all aspects of the website, including authentication.  I moved all of my database CRUD procedures into the Class Library.  The Blazor app authenticates and uses Roles/Claims to authorize different pages.  But, how do I extend that authorization to my Class Library, so that I can use the same Class/Function decorations to designate authorized roles/claims?  Here is an example of how my application is setup:

**Blazor App - Startup.cs**

The Blazor app has a reference to the Class Library and corresponding "Using statements". I then inject those classes into the ConfigureServices method, for use in pages.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   //...adding other required services
   //  Inject class from my Class Library
    services.AddTransient<ISqlDataAccess, SqlDataAccess >();
    services.AddTransient<IPeopleData, PeopleData>();
}
```

Here is an example of how I use the injected classes, to pull data from my database.  I can implement roles access here, but I also want to implement it in the Class library.

**Somepage.Razor**

```
@page "/mysite/people"
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
@using DataAccessLibrary
@using DataAccessLibrary.Models
@inject IPeopleData_db

//html to display data
@code{
 //list of the returned data set, using the model, People
 List<PeopleModel> people = new List<PeopleModel>();
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
    people = await _db.GetAllPeople();
 }
}
```

**DataAccessLibarary**

**IPeopleData.cs**

```
public interface IPeopleData
{
   Task<PeopleModel> GetAllPeople();      
}
```

**PeopleData.cs**

```
public class PeopleData : IPeopleData
{
  // ISqlDataAccess is a class that handles basic CRUD calls to the database.  Uses Dapper easy object mapping
  private readonly ISqlDataAccess _db;

  public PeopleData(ISqlDataAccess db)
  {
    _db = db;
  }
   public Task<List<PersonModel>> GetAllPeople()
   {
       string sql = "select * from dbo.People";
       return _db.LoadData<PersonModel, dynamic>(sql, new { }); 
   }
}
```

So, I can add authorization attributes to the Blazor pages, using [Authorize(Roles = "admin")].  But, this does not protect the Class Library that manages all the database connection stuff.  How can I extent the role based access control to that library, so that I can use similar decorations to my classes/functions, like [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly:  There is no mechanism for adding authorization to standard DotNetCore classes, which is what your library code is.  Authorize is applied to components.

You need to structure your application applying "Separation of Concerns" principles to solve your problems.

You need to reconsider:

```
services.AddTransient<ISqlDataAccess, SqlDataAccess >();
```

It will almost certainly leak memory like a sieve.  A SQL access service should be either Scoped or normally Singleton.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the issue with my services injection.  Do you know of any tutorials for Blazor that illustrate "Separation of Concerns" concepts?